# why my authentication isn't working .Net code Azure AD "The signature key was not found"

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, authorization

I am using the below code to authorize

```
.AddJwtBearer(schemaname, options =>
               {
                   options.Audience = AddJwtBearerConfigurations[xxx].Audience;
                   options.Authority = AddJwtBearerConfigurations[xxx].Authority;
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; 
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidateIssuer = false,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                       ValidateLifetime = false,
                       ValidateTokenReplay = false,
                       RequireSignedTokens = false,
                   };
               })
```

I am using Application ID URI as Audience and [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantID%7D) as Authority
I keep getting error

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
> signature is invalid" WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",
> error_description="The signature is invalid" WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
> error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
> signature is invalid" WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",
> error_description="The signature is invalid" WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
> error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not
> found"

I tried clinetID, decode the jwt and use "aud" and still getting 401

any help

Update, i started sending IssuerSigningKey and now error i dug out of output

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: {schemaName} was not authenticated. Failure message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"The signature key was not found"*** may occur when you don't include signing key in your **Startup.cs** configuration file.

To resolve the error, try adding **`IssuerSigningKey`** in the code by modifying it like below if helpful:

```cs
options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidIssuer = "Your_Token_Issuer",
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdef123"))
                   };
```

Please find below links that may give you some pointers to resolve the error:

[c# - Bearer error - invalid_token - The signature key was not found - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563661/bearer-error-invalid-token-the-signature-key-was-not-found)

[Creating And Validating JWT Tokens In C# .NET - .NET Core Tutorials (dotnetcoretutorials.com)](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/15/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/)

[JWT Validation and Authorization in ASP.NET Core - .NET Blog (microsoft.com)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: where can I get this signingkey from? can i decode the access token and find it ?

Comment: You can make use of existing public key or create one key by referring this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294373/net-core-issuersigningkey-from-file-for-jwt-bearer-authentication). You can decode your token via jwt.io and find **`alg`**, **`x5t`** and **`kid`** in header section to know key details !

Comment: good news, now i am getting only WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" but still 401

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: {schemaName} was not authenticated. Failure message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you edit your question with modified code like how **`IssuerSigningKey`** is included? Check this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621195/asp-net-core-authentication-with-jwt-the-signature-is-invalid?rq=1)  once!